# Can i have multiple overlays in one page in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a UI Design like this

[image]

The problem is that I cannot open Multiple Overlays.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would've been easier if you had shared the source code. You also can achieve the overlay using `Stack`, positioning the overlay widgets at the top of Stack and the chat page at the bottom. I am sharing the minimal code to show how this can be achieved.

The concept is getting the global position of the tapped message widget and using that position to lay the overlays in Stack. Here is the code.

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});
  final String title;
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool showOverlay = false;
  Offset? targetPos;
  Widget? target;

  _showOverlay(Offset position, Widget? target) {
    setState(() {
      targetPos = position;
      this.target = target;
      showOverlay = true;
    });
  }

  _hideOverlay() {
    setState(() {
      showOverlay = false;
      targetPos = null;
      target = null;
    });
  }

  final double padding = 8;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          ListView(
            children: [
              for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                Message(
                  onTap: _showOverlay,
                  padding: padding,
                )
            ],
          ),

          ///Mimics the overlay
          if (showOverlay)
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: _hideOverlay,
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.black54,
              ),
            ),
          if (showOverlay)
            Positioned(
                top: (targetPos?.dy)! - 70,
                left: targetPos?.dx,
                child: Container(
                  //Your Reaction widget
                  height: 60,
                  width: 120,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                )),
          if (showOverlay)
            Positioned(
                top: (targetPos?.dy)! - padding,
                left: (targetPos?.dx)! - padding,
                child: target ?? const SizedBox()),
          if (showOverlay)
            Positioned(
                top: (targetPos?.dy)! + 50,
                left: targetPos?.dx,
                child: Container(
                  //Your action widget
                  height: 60,
                  width: 120,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

typedef OnTap = void Function(Offset globalPosition, Widget? target);

class Message extends StatefulWidget {
  final double padding;
  final OnTap onTap;

  const Message({super.key, required this.onTap, required this.padding});

  @override
  State<Message> createState() => _MessageState();
}

class _MessageState extends State<Message> {
  Offset? position;
  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      final RenderBox box = key.currentContext?.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
      position = box.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
      setState(() {});
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  final GlobalKey key = GlobalKey();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(widget.padding),
      child: GestureDetector(
        behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
        key: key,
        onTap: position != null
            ? () {
                widget.onTap(position!, widget);
              }
            : null,
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: const Text("Hello"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the time and effort, it works very well.